# WPF Printing to Epson TM-H6000 Slip

Tags: wpf, printing

I am trying to print to an Epson TM-H6000 Slip printer.  I am able to print to the receipt printer but not the slip.

```
PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
printDlg.ShowDialog();
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run("Some text goes here")));
IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;
printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Testing");
```

Selecting the receipt will print the text to the receipt printer.  Sending the same command to slip, it feeds the paper but does not print anything on it.

Edit: I should note that it does print a windows test page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this however it is not a good solution.  Basically, if I set the font size 19 or larger it prints.  If it is under 19 then it just feeds the page.

I don't know if this is an issue with MS `PrintDocument` or Epson's printer driver.  If anyone has an idea please reply!